# POST Interactions REST API - Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api

In the following code, I pass in the REST url, the access token and the journeys I want it act on - in the from of an array of objects.

The issue is that the request always fails with a 404 - Object found not... However, I have yet to figured out why.

Any clue were as to why this is happening?

```
  function pauseJourneys(url, token, journeys){
    try{
      var endpoint = '/interaction/v1/interactions/pause/'
      var payload = {
        "ExtendWaitEndDates":false,
        "PausedDays":14,
        "ProcessWaitUntilEvents":true,
        "GuardrailAction":"Stop",
        "RetainContactInjectionWhileJourneyPaused":true
      }
      var bearerToken = "Bearer " + token
      var headers = ["Authorization"]
      var values = [bearerToken]
      
      for(var i = 0; i < journeys.length(); i++){
        var res = HTTP.Post( url + endpoint + journeys[i].definitionId + '?versionNumber=' + journeys[i].version, "application/json", Stringify(payload), headers, values)
        
        Write(Stringify(res))
      }
      
    }catch(e){
      Write(Stringify(e));
    }
  }
```

Postman request returns the following:

```
{
    "message": "Interaction matching criteria not found.",
    "errorcode": 30003,
    "documentation": ""
}
```

Comment: Have you tested it in Postman for a single journey definition?

Comment: I have not tested in postman. However, I am not sure if that will help. But I will give it a shot.

Comment: I test any REST calls in Postman first, since it's easier to iterate.  Postman can also generate JS code for you, which is a good place to start for implementing it in a CloudPage or Script Activity.

Comment: I test in postman and the response is more or less the same - as soon in the revised post.

Comment: Which key in the interaction object should I use in this call.

definitionId or id

Comment: Looks like it should be `id` when I do a retrieve with `https://{{et_subdomain}}.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/interaction/v1/interactions`

Comment: Yelp is was Id and not definitionId. Which, is confusing as the documentation states definitionId. 

I switched from using the definitionId to the Id and Postman showed the actual message behind why the call was failing. 

400 Error that postman showed: 
"An interaction cannot be paused when configured to queue new contact injections and have scheduled automations.""

Comment: Any idea how I can get this error from the response in the cloud page? Because at the moment it it just,

Comment: e: {"message":"An error occurred when attempting to evaluate a HTTPPost function call. See inner exception for details.","description":"ExactTarget.OMM.FunctionExecutionException: An error occurred when attempting to evaluate a HTTPPost function call. See inner exception for details.\r\n Error Code: OMM_FUNC_EXEC_ERROR\r\n - from Jint --> \r\n\r\n --- inner exception 1---\r\n\r\nSystem.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request. - from System\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n"}

Comment: But postman show: 

"{
    "message": "An interaction cannot be paused when configured to queue new contact injections and have scheduled automations.".",
    "errorcode": 10000,
    "documentation": ""
}"

Answer (score 1):

I'd add some debugging statements and execute it in a CloudPage:

```javascript
function pauseJourneys(url, token, journeys){

  try {

    var endpoint = '/interaction/v1/interactions/pause/'
    var payload = {
      "ExtendWaitEndDates":false,
      "PausedDays":14,
      "ProcessWaitUntilEvents":true,
      "GuardrailAction":"Stop",
      "RetainContactInjectionWhileJourneyPaused":true
    }

    var bearerToken = "Bearer " + token
    var headers = ["Authorization"]
    var values = [bearerToken]
    
    for(var i = 0; i < journeys.length(); i++){

      Write("<hr>url: " + url);
      Write("<br>endpoint: " + endpoint);
      Write("<br>journeys["+i+"].definitionId: " + journeys[i].definitionId);
      Write("<br>journeys["+i+"].version: " + journeys[i].version);

      //var res = HTTP.Post( url + endpoint + journeys[i].definitionId + '?versionNumber=' + journeys[i].version, "application/json", Stringify(payload), headers, values)
      
      //Write(Stringify(res))
    }
    
  } catch(e) {
    Write("<br>e: " + Stringify(e));
  }

}
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. I will do that.